# Dropdownlist and categories subcategories

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I was try to load unlimited categories to dropdownlist but I failed.

```
**Categories**
ID, MainCategoryID, CatName, Description, dateCreated, isActive
1, 0, Cars, "blabla", 26.06.2012, True
2, 1, Ferrari, "blabla", 26.06.2012, True
3, 1, Lamborgini, "blabla", 26.06.2012, True
4, 2, F-40, "blabla", 26.06.2012, True
5, 2, F-50, "blabla", 26.06.2012, True
6, 0, Motorbikes, "blabla", 26.06.2012, True

- MainCategory
  -- SubCategory1
  -- SubCategory2
     -- SubSubCategory1
- MainCategory
- MainCategory
  -- SubCategory3
     -- SubSub .. so on
```

Is it possible to do that in dropdownlist control?

Comment: why can not you use treeview control?

Comment: Because my boss wants me to do that with dropdownlist :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible. You only need a little **recursion**.
Can be done in your sql query itself.

If you are using sql server you can achieve recursion using [common table expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

If you are confused about this, put a comment and I will write the query to show you.

```
WITH cat(ord,lev, id, mainID, catName) AS
(
    SELECT ID*POWER(100, 3) AS ord, 1 AS lev, ID, MainCategoryID,CatName FROM test WHERE MainCategoryID =0
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT cat.ord + test.ID * POWER(100, 3-lev) AS ord,lev+1 AS lev, test.ID, test.MainCategoryID, test.CatName AS CatName FROM test INNER JOIN cat ON test.MainCategoryID = cat.ID
)
SELECT * FROM cat ORDER BY ord
```

lev column gives you the level of the row.
ord column is used to order your items. This example allows for upto 100 ids and 3 levels.

Though I have ordered the data here, this is best done in c#, using recursion there.

Comment: Actually I could not write the query. I inspected some recursion queries but i was confused. If you help me to write it i will be happy. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks for codes but I think there is a problem. I mean it works but I don't get it. How I order them like -maincat and then subcats.<br>check that screenshot. http://i1084.photobucket.com/albums/j415/kad1r/Untitled.png

Comment: Yes, that's really what I need. Thanks for query. Now I just need to inspect the query and understand the logic...